# Sum contents based on matching

Tags: excel

Imagine the following table:

```
Value  Classification
100        A
600
200        B
300        A
400        C
500        B
```

Notice that some of the values have no classification, they are to be ignored.

And the qualifier table:

```
Classification   Useable
     A            TRUE
     B            FALSE
     C            TRUE
```

How can I sum the values on the first table, by matching their second column with the second table, in case its "Useable"?

I tried using `VLOOKUP` as so `=SUMPRODUCT(K10:K18;IFERROR(--VLOOKUP(M10:M18;R16:S18;2;FALSE);0))` however it wont work, even though the VLOOKUP returns an array, when I use `IFERROR` it will convert the bloody thing to a scalar not an array. (`K10:K18` is the "Value" column and `M10:M18` is the "Classification" column).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you have to use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it an array formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this SUM() array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(LOOKUP($B$2:$B$7;$C$2:$C$4;$D$2:$D$4);FALSE);$A$2:$A$7))
```

Being and array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, works like a charm!

Any ideas as to why my version didnt work?

Comment: VLOOKUP does not play well with arrays.  It is not built for that.  Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer

Comment: Done, you're a life saver!